# Avoid copying current directory but files only via sftp

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, sftp

When I'm copying files via sftp with this command:

```
echo 'put -rp /home/rof/clone/dist' > put.txt
sftp -b put.txt andreyshedko@185.206.144.61:/home/andreyshedko/Applications/agroproject-api/stage/stage/
```

It's creating `dist` folder in the destination, while I need copy only `dist` folder content - files and children directories?

Comment: Add a /* after dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`echo 'put -rp /home/rof/clone/dist/*' > put.txt`

this will echo all underlying directories and files

---

If you just want files, do

`echo 'put -rp /home/rof/clone/dist/*.*' > put.txt`

Dont mind the formatting. I'm on mobile.